# How to replace pandas dataframe column A value base on the value of another column B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hava a data frame, for example
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,np.nan],[4,5,np.nan],[7,8,9]])
so it would be

```
        sku  r1   r2
    0    1   2  NaN
    1    4   5  NaN
    2    7   8  9.0
```

if I would like to change r1 column's value base on r2, I mean if r2 is Not Nan, then use r2's value replace r1'value, otherwise keep r1 no change

So the result would be:

```
        sku  r1   r2
    0    1   2  NaN
    1    4   5  NaN
    2    7   9.0  9.0
```

so you see, change 8 to 9.0 in third case in this example.
I am a new learner of pandas, it takes me time to find a solution for this.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df['r1'] = df['r1'].mask(df['r2'].notnull(), df['r2'])
print (df)

   sku   r1   r2
0    1  2.0  NaN
1    4  5.0  NaN
2    7  9.0  9.0
```

Or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['r2'].notnull(), 'r1'] = df['r2']
print (df)
   sku   r1   r2
0    1  2.0  NaN
1    4  5.0  NaN
2    7  9.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where`:

```
df['r1'] = np.where(df['r2'].notnull(),df['r2'],df['r1'])
df
```

Output:

```
   sku   r1   r2
0    1  2.0  NaN
1    4  5.0  NaN
2    7  9.0  9.0
```